# Invalid template file error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, template, theme, magento-catalog

In my custom theme, I added custom template for which I am getting invalid template file error in system.log. My xml file loctaion:

```
app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

My template file location

```
app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_catalog/templates/product/view/size_guide.phtml
```

catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="size_guide" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/size_guide.phtml" group="detailed_info">
<arguments>
    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Size Guide</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
<!-- this is code to add new tab end -->
</body>
</page>
```

size_guide.phtml

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('size_guide')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Magento looks for the template file in module-catalog and gives the error when not found. Why does Magento not pick up the template file from my theme?

Answer (score 1):

place your size_guide.phtml in your module i.e {code}/{vendor}/{module}/view/frontend/templates/product/view/size_guide.phtml it worked for me.

Comment: i have placed the template file as app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/size_guide.phtml. Still its not working?

Comment: than check your xml file. i think you are not calling template file properly...otherwise share the files we will check.

Comment: i have given my xml file contents above, i am calling the template file as: Magento_Catalog::product/view/size_guide.phtml.

Comment: remove Magento_Catalog and give your module name.

Comment: you mean removing Magento_Catalog from app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/ and create new module there, placing my xml file like  app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/mymodule/layout/? if so then should i keep the template file as app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/size_guide.phtml?

Comment: just change the xml ....replace Magento_Catalog with myvender_mymodule and  place that file in your module i.e templates  /templates/product/view/

Comment: live server pick and load the template file with same file structure and setting as i have given in my question details above, but localhost does not load file and i get 'invalide template file' error in system.log

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the name of the module is not is proper case.

When creating the folder structure,

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

replace the `Magento_catalog` with `Magento_Catalog`.
That will direct Magento to pick up the proper template.

Answer (score 0):

Your size_,guide.phtml file is need to store in `app/design/vendor/theme/frontend/Magento_Catalog/templates/size_guide.phtml`

Because, you had used default module name `Magento_Catalog` that's why you can't store in `app/code`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overriding the `catalog_product_view.xml` in your theme, you have to create the folders `override/base` inside your layout folder. Hence your layout file path should be like the following

```
app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_catalog/layout/override/base/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Now run the setup upgrade command and refresh. This has worked for me.